Cleaning dirty buffers with a background process (bgwriter) in Postgres
I can't understand the statistics I get from pg_stat_bgwriter.
If you believe these statistics, then the background process (bgwriter) does not clear the RAM from dirty buffers, unlike the checkpoint. If I understood correctly, then the background process should simultaneously clear the RAM of dirty buffers, if any.
My background process settings are set to default:
bgwriter_delay = 200ms
bgwriter_lru_max pages = 100
bgwriter_lru_multiplier = 2

The checkpoint is performed every 20 minutes.
At the same time, sometimes the background process (bgwriter) clears data from RAM, but it does this quite rarely, i.e. it works. Should I be worried about this?
I guess I need to back up my words with statistics. So I took measurements during the day and I see that checkpoints_timed cleared 1GB of data during the day, and buffers_checkpoint 0.

I have no idea what you are asking.  Maybe show us an example of what it is you are seeing but then not understanding.  Also, this type of thing sometimes changes from version to version.


At the same time, sometimes the background process (bgwriter) clears data from RAM, but it does this quite rarely, i.e. it works. Should I be worried about this?

No, that is exactly what it is supposed to be doing.
Most of the buffers get cleaned (written out to disk) by the checkpointer. But without the background writer, it could happen that between checkpoints all or almost all shared buffers become dirty.  Then a backend that needs to read data into shared buffers would first have to write out and flush a dirty buffer before it could evict it, which is bad for performance.
With the background worker doing its job, a backend can always find a clean buffer to evict easily, even if buffers are dirtied at a high rate.
